# React web app routes not working with query string by using nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I am trying to host my react website using nginx. everything works fine except the routes having query string.

```sh
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

```
http:// example.com                          //works fine
http:// example.com/courses                  //works fine
http:// example.com/courses?type=software    //not working shows blank page.
http:// example.com/courses?type=software&institute=xyz    //not working shows blank page.
```

Please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer.

We can achieve this by two ways.

### 1. $query_string

```sh
location / {
             try_files $uri /index.html?$query_string; 
        }
```

### 2. $is_args

```sh
location / { 
             try_files $uri /index.html$is_args$args;
        }
```